# How do I put my entire query in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT
    AvHours.LineNumber,
    (SProd.PoundsMade / (AvHours.AvailableHRS - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS))) AS Throughput,
    SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS) AS [Lost Time], 
    (SUM(cast(ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS AS decimal(10,1))) * 100) / (cast(AvHours.AvailableHRS AS decimal(10,1))) AS [%DownTime],
    SUM(SProd.PoundsMade) AS [Pounds Made],
   (SProd.PoundsMade / (AvHours.AvailableHRS - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS))) *  SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS) AS [Pounds Lost]
FROM 
    rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs AvHours
INNER JOIN  
    rpt_Line_Shift_Prod SProd ON AvHours.LineNumber = SProd.LineNumber 
                              AND AvHours.Shiftnumber = SProd.Shiftnumber
INNER JOIN
    rpt_Line_Shift_ProdDownTime ProdDtime ON (AvHours.LineNumber = ProdDtime.LineNumber AND 
                                           AvHours.Shiftnumber = ProdDtime.Shiftnumber)
GROUP BY 
     AvHours.LineNumber, SProd.PoundsMade, AvHours.AvailableHRS
ORDER BY 
     AvHours.LineNumber
```

Comment: [Read the fabulous online documentation!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new stored procedure with the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedureNameHere
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

END
GO
```

in your specific case the statement should look like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedureNameHere
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        AvHours.LineNumber,
        (SProd.PoundsMade / (AvHours.AvailableHRS - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS))) AS Throughput,
        SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS) AS [Lost Time], 
        (SUM(cast(ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS AS decimal(10,1))) * 100) / (cast(AvHours.AvailableHRS AS decimal(10,1))) AS [%DownTime],
        SUM(SProd.PoundsMade) AS [Pounds Made],
       (SProd.PoundsMade / (AvHours.AvailableHRS - SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS))) *  SUM (ProdDtime.DownTimeHRS) AS [Pounds Lost]
    FROM 
        rpt_Line_Shift_AvailableHrs AvHours
    INNER JOIN  
        rpt_Line_Shift_Prod SProd ON AvHours.LineNumber = SProd.LineNumber 
                                  AND AvHours.Shiftnumber = SProd.Shiftnumber
    INNER JOIN
        rpt_Line_Shift_ProdDownTime ProdDtime ON (AvHours.LineNumber = ProdDtime.LineNumber AND 
                                               AvHours.Shiftnumber = ProdDtime.Shiftnumber)
    GROUP BY 
         AvHours.LineNumber, SProd.PoundsMade, AvHours.AvailableHRS
    ORDER BY 
         AvHours.LineNumber

END
GO
```

Please note that Microsoft SQL Management Studio can automatically create a stub for your stored procedure (pretty much the first code snippet in this answer) right clicking the item "Stored Procedures" under [Your DB]/Programmability and selecting "New Stored Procedure..." from the contextual menu:

[image]